# CSS rounded borders in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, css

How do I give Firefox rounded borders using border-radius? I am using Firefox 14 on Ubuntu.

**Edit:**
I have tried

```
-moz-border-radius
```

and all the other browser specific comments, none of them have worked. I had already found this after searching on Google, and that is why I asked here.

Does it make any difference if I'm using KDE? I have already added Firefox in the window-specific overrides.

My [userChrome.css](http://pastebin.com/0c1zR2G5) file starts with this:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
```

Is it supposed to implemented differently? The rest of the css codes I have used work perfectly. Thanks!

***THE RESULT:***
I wanted to round the corners of the entire border, but apparently it's impossible. Sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks for your trouble!

Comment: -1: A simple search could have found you an answer.

Comment: Did you google this first? http://bit.ly/NzxNJR

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing I found gave me rounded borders. Very snarky, @flem. I did my research

Comment: send me link where is put the html and css code

Comment: I've linked the "userChrome.css" to my userChrome.css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, have you specified a [**selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) for your property? [The file you linked](http://pastebin.com/0c1zR2G5) lacks them. Try this:

```
* {
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It still didn't make the browser borders rounded, but made the bookmarks tab and the window border rounded, so it looks better. Not the answer I was looking for, but still something I liked.

Comment: Hm, you might ask a new question which is more specific. When people read your title "... in Firefox", they'll think about HTML. You should ask "Rounded corners for *the browser window* of Firefox on Ubuntu"

Answer (score 1):

The -moz-border-radius css property would take care of this.

Here are the browser specific border radius properties:

```
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
```

Comment: It should work.  There must be something you are doing wrong then elsewhere.  I do this about 10 times a day.

Comment: I am trying to make the entire Firefox window have rounded borders, not just an element within. Is it correct?

Comment: so the body tag?  If so, you might be having a height issue.  If it is the body tag you are trying to add border radius, I might have a link that will help.  Let me know.

Comment: Is there a link where I can look at the rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm a beginner in CSS, just started a day back so that I could configure userChrome.css :)
But I think the body tag is what I'm trying to add the border radius to

Comment: Try this:  html,body {width: 100%; height: 100%;} body{border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px;}

Comment: I have linked my userChrome.css in the question

Comment: No, didn't give anything. And should I move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Just the CSS doesn't really help, as I can't see the problem that is occurring.  First thing, looking at your css, you are applying a border-radius on line 1 to nothing it looks like...and you aren't specifying either -webkit-border-radius or -moz-border-radius....

Comment: What else should I post? I have edited only the userChrome.css file, nothing else. How should I implement the commands then? I tried applying all 3, too, and when that didn't work I thought I had to use only the css code, and not the gecko

Comment: If you have html, paste that in your original post...that will help any of us out, as it will allow us to use the exact html and css you have to figure out or reproduce the issue.  Here's a screenshot to better explain what I am seeing as an issue: http://screencast.com/t/yWTRqoR636G

Comment: Yes, that is what it reads now, and it didn't work. No, I don't have the html, as far as I know... Can I see the link? Maybe I can find something and post if I find out my mistake?

Comment: Okay, that still didn't work... but anyway, doesn't "body" refer to display portion of the browser? I want the entire Firefox window border to be rounded

Comment: well in that case, I believe it is impossible to do so.  If you are talking about the browser itself.  I'm not sure why someone would want to do that anyways...There might be a way to do so using JavaScript, but I'm not entirely sure as I have never needed or have had the want to do so.

Comment: Yes, I meant the browser. Because KDE puts a border for all windows, and for Firefox, I prefer the browser without the border. Unfortunately, without the border, all the corners are sharp, so I wanted to change that. Thank for your trouble, though...

Comment: I would suggest adding another tag for javascript in your question...as my thought process leads me to believe this is something only javascript can fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
-moz-border-radius: <radius>px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `-moz-border-radius` property for the border radius. For more info please visit

[rounded border](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

Comment: I'm trying to give the entire firefox window rounded borders, not just an element within it.